# Something like reference counting or shared pointers for database rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

First of all, I am using Postgres 9.1.

I have a table named filepaths and other tables that have rows that point to the id of their corresponding filepaths.  Is there a common design approach for reference counting the filepaths so that when other rows are dropped and there are no longer any references to a particular filepath row, it can be dropped as well?

Example:

```
    [filepaths]
    1 | c:\windows\system32\test.exe
    2 | c:\windows\calc.exe

    [events_2011_08_30]
    [1][timestamp][other data] [ filepaths = 1]
    [2][timestamp][other data] [ filepaths = 2]

    [events_2011_08_31]
    [1][timestamp][other data] [ filepaths = 1]
```

So I will be storing data in tables to partition it, and I want to delete old tables when they are older than say 30 days (will still have them archived).  In the above example, let's assume there are only those two events_ tables.  If I delete the 2011_08_30, I would desire a way to know that nothing is pointing to filepaths '2' and therefore remove it, but know that a row is still pointing to filepaths '1' and therefore retain it.

Any thoughts, suggestions, etc? I believe some of the strategies I have read, at least for postgres and triggers, still have race conditions about which thread got a lock first on the primary key column and other related issues.

Thanks!

Comment: @ Ben It's not quite clear to me why you need to check if anything else points to `filepaths=2` when deleting `events_2011_08_30`. When you use an ´on delete no action` constraint, `2` in `filepaths` isn't getting deleted (if I understand your requirement correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need reference counting. (you could implement it using triggers, if you *really* want it) 
What you want is called a foreign key [constraint]

The simplest way to clean up the filepath table is by using a NOT EXISTS construct, eg

```
DELETE FROM filepaths fp
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM events ev where ev.file_id = fp.file_id)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM events_version_xxx ev where ev.file_id = fp.file_id)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM events_version_yyy ev where ev.file_id = fp.file_id)
...
;
```

This is ugly. But the database model is ugly, too.

Comment: Well, I agree that approach would work, but we're going to have tens of millions or hundreds of millions of rows, so that could take a very, very long time to complete... still, I appreciate it!

Comment: But the real question is: what is the cost of having some cruft in the pathnames table? How I understand it, the real big tables are the events_version_xxx tables. Maybe just let it rot for a while and trim it periodically.

Comment: You're right, that might just be the case where on a saturday night or something we trim down every month.  Do you have any suggestions to make it the database model less "ugly" ?

Comment: Well the real wtf seems to me the moving (and dropping off) of the tables. Very similar to reference counting would be to put a timestamp into the filepath-table, which has to be touched or synchronized on every insert/update of the "active" events-table. If your primary access is "row at a time" (which I suspect), this could be done by a trigger, otherwise an update/insert rule could be more efficient. Both methods have a large impact on performance, because the number of affected rows/disk pages is more or less doubled.

Comment: Well the tables don't necessarily have to be chopped off / deleted, that's mostly for speed and storage size since we basically care about the last 30 or 60 days and beyond that it can go into some archive somewhere.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, I would challenge the desire to partition your data over one table per date.  I would suggest, instead, simply having a column in your table named `effective_date` or similar.

In terms of having a reference count on `filepaths`, that can be accomplished in several ways, but to ensure encapsulation of code, I'd recommend one of the following two approaches...

**1. A Stored Procedure API**

By ensuring that *all* INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE operations are processed through Stored Procedures you can then also encapsulate increment and decrement of the reference counter on `filepaths`.  No user/login then needs access to the tables for write activities, instead they just use the Stored Procedure.

**2. Triggers**

A trigger can be created on each `events` table to encapsulate the reference counter increment and decrement code.  Whenever the table contents are modified, the trigger fires and propagates the consequences of your business logic.

Many people shy away from triggers as they feel they are hidden away, and can have complex interactions if over used.  I, however, think they are extremely useful.

In either case, everything is MUCH simplified by having just a single table, rather than multiple tables.

Additionally, most SQL Design patterns do not account for "deleting a table" to be a Business As Usual action.  Creating or Removing tables, in my opinion, should be treated as design changes, not data activities.

Comment: Well 1 table would be nice, but to speed up queries and make it easier to delete old events, we're going to have to (at least with my level of understanding) use partitioning.  We have single tables now and they're so massive that it takes forever to do fairly simple things like deleting all events older than a particular time, or filtering for a UI....I will think about your answer more! Thanks!

Comment: Also, from discussions I had with others, it seemed like most data warehousing situations do partition tables by date or other criteria...

Comment: I've dealt with terabyte size data warehouses and found that data partitioning is more often *not required* than *required*.  I would look at the suitability of the data structure and/or indexes to the operations you are performing.  Also, when partitioning is used, I highly recommend *against* having tables for specific date periods; rather, use relative period such as having one table for "the last 30 days", another for "the 335 days before that" and a third for "everything before that" (or similar), then have nightly batch processes to move the data around.